# Performance. Look for a substring. substr vs find

Tags: c++, string, performance

Say we have a string var "sA" and I would like to check whether the string "123" is at the end of the sA.

What is better to do and why:

- `if(sA.length() > 2) sA.substr(sA.length()-3) == "123"`
- `if(sA.length() > 2) sA.find("123", sA.length() -3) != string::npos`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not test it? Just time the two methods and compare.

Comment: Definetly not substr, you don't need to make a substring if you only want to check.

Comment: The second version seems to do the least number of comparisons and string copies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second code fragment avoids creation of two temporary objects (one for the `"123"` converted to `std::string`, the other for the return value of `substr`), so in theory it should be faster. However, micro-optimizations of this sort rarely pay off: it is unlikely that you would see a substantial gain from using the second form over the first one if you apply this optimization randomly.

Of course the situation is different if your profiler tells you that your program spends a substantial percentage of its time checking the ending of the string like this; in this case, the optimization will likely help.

Comment: From experience I must disagree here in so far that it makes a real difference if most of your application is doing such things. One of them does an allocation, while the other does not, and usually allocation is quite expensive. If the application is spending most of the time comparing substrings that way, it makes a noticeable difference; hence I agree in so far that it is likely a micro optimization that should not be considered until a profiler shows it is necessary.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks for the note. I clarified the answer to point out that the optimization is worth making if the profiler tells you so.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is critical, I don't think you can get any faster than this (compared to the other methods, no allocations are necessary):

```
const char needle[] = "abc";
const char *haystack;
const int len = strlen(haystack);

if (len<sizeof(needle))
    return false;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(needle); i++)
    if (needle[i] != haystack[len-sizeof(needle)+i])
        return false;
return true;
```

Obviously various micro-optimizations are possible, but the approach is the fastest I can think of.

---

A more C++y version, using std::string for the haystack:

```
const char needle[] = "abc";
const std::string haystack;
const int len = haystack.length();

if (len<sizeof(needle))
    return false;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(needle); i++)
    if (needle[i] != haystack[len-sizeof(needle)+i])
        return false;
return true;
```

notice that, as long as `std::string::operator[]` is O(1), the two listings have the same performance characteristics

Comment: Is this still faster if you have to allocate the char arrays first, as the OP stated he is assuming C++ strings as a starting point?

Comment: The OP seems to be using std::string for the haystack only. Notice that you can replace `const char *haystack` with `std::string haystack` and `const int len = strlen(haystack)` with `const int len = haystack.length()` and the code will still be valid C++ with the same performance characteristics (as long as `std::string::operator[]` runs in O(1)). In particular, no allocations will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This code probably is faster than the ones you are testing.
But you will only know if you do some testing.

```
bool EndsWith(const string &strValue, const string &strEnd)
{            
    int iDiference = strValue.size() - strEnd.size();
    if(iDiference >= 0)     
        return (memcmp(strValue.c_str() + iDiference, strEnd.c_str(), strEnd.size()) == 0);

    return false;
}
```